# How to solve MS Access login case sensitive?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I share my code which I use in MS Access database login form.

Can anyone help me solve the case sensitivity problem?

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click() 
    Dim UserLevel As Integer 
    Dim USER_NAME As String 
    Dim TemLoginID As String

    If IsNull(Me.LOGINID) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your login ID", vbInformation, "Login Id is required."
        Me.LOGINID.SetFocus 
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.PASSWORD) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your password", vbInformation, "Password Id is required."
        Me.PASSWORD.SetFocus 
    Else
        If (IsNull(DLookup("USER_NAME", "USER", "USER_ID = '" & Me.LOGINID.Value & "'"))) Or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("PASSWORD", "USER", "PASSWORD = '" & Me.PASSWORD.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect ID or Password." 
        Else
            TemLoginID = Me.LOGINID.Value
            USER_NAME = DLookup("USER_NAME", "USER", "USER_ID = '" & Me.LOGINID.Value & "'")
            UserLevel = DLookup("DIGINATION", "USER", "USER_ID = '" & Me.LOGINID.Value & "'")
            DoCmd.Close
            If UserLevel = 1 Then
                MsgBox "Welcome to our TravelSoft! You are login as a Admin."
                DoCmd.OpenForm "DESHBOARD"
                Forms![DESHBOARD]![LOGINID] = TemLoginID
                Forms![DESHBOARD]![USER] = USER_NAME    
            Else
                If UserLevel = 2 Then
                    MsgBox "Welcome to our TravelSoft! You are login as a Manager."
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "DESHBOARD"
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]![LOGINID] = TemLoginID
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!Reissue.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!void.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!adm.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!particular.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!userid.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!Profile.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]!AGENT.Enabled = False
                    Forms![DESHBOARD]![USER] = USER_NAME
                Else
                    If UserLevel = 3 Then
                        MsgBox "Welcome to our TravelSoft! You are login as a Accounts."
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "DESHBOARD"
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]![LOGINID] = TemLoginID
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!Reissue.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!void.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!adm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!particular.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!userid.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!Profile.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!AGENT.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!reissue_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!void_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!adm_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!Passenger_information.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!ticket_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]![USER] = USER_NAME
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Welcome to our TravelSoft! You are login as a User."
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "DESHBOARD"
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]![LOGINID] = TemLoginID
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!reissue_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!void_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!adm_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!ticket_confirm.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!Profile.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!AGENT.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]!userid.Enabled = False
                        Forms![DESHBOARD]![USER] = USER_NAME
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? I assume you are trying to force login names to be a specific case? Also, your code would be a great candidate for a `Select Case` [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement).

Comment: Maybe use `Option Compare Binary` in module header https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/modules/options/index.html#OptionCompare or review http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=25944

Comment: You should also consider hashing and salting your passwords, especially if this tool is exposed to the broader internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *StrComp*:

```
DLookup("USER_NAME", "USER", "StrComp(USER_ID, '" & Me.LOGINID.Value & "', " & vbBinaryCompare & ") = 0")
```